# Use inferred generic param type of one function to type other functions

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings, typescript-generics

I'm building an API to render a schema graph.

Here's what it looks like (ultra-simplified)

```
interface Node {
  name: string;
}

type NodeNames<T extends Node[]> = T[number]["name"]; // All node names as union of string literal

type Scalars = 'Int' | 'Boolean' | 'String'

type AllTypes<T extends Node[]> = NodeNames<T> | Scalars

interface Schema<T extends Node[]> {
  createNode(name: String, fields: Record<string, AllTypes<T>>): Node;

  render(types: T[]): string;
}

const s: Schema = { // generic not captured => "TypeError: Generic type 'Schema<T>' requires 1 type"

  render(types) {
    // print types
    return ''
  },
  createNode(name, fields) {
    return { name, fields };
  }
};

const Blog = s.createNode("Blog", { users: "User" });
const User = s.createNode("User", { posts: "Post" });
const Post = s.createNode("Post", { title: "String", comments: 'Comment' }); // <== Expected type error because 'Comment' node doesn't exist

s.render([Blog, User, Post]);
```

**I would like to make sure that one cannot reference a type that wasn't registered in the `Schema.render` from the `Schema.createNode` function.**

In the example above, `fields` should basically be of type: `Record<string, Scalars | 'User' | 'Post' | 'Blog'`, where `User | Post | Blog` is inferred from the nodes passed to `s.render`

To do that, I'd like to infer the names of the nodes passed to the `render` function, in order to type the values of the param `fields` of `Schema.createNode`.

Unfortunately, generics are only captured by function parameters if declared on a function level, and not if declared on an interface level (which makes sense).

How can I reuse the inferred generic of `s.render<T extends Node[]>(nodes: T)` to type the function `createNode(name: string, fields: AllTypes<T>)` where `T` is the same inferred type shared between the two functions?

Is there a way to make this work? (even with a slightly different API)

Thanks

Comment: You create `const s` of type `Schema`, not giving it a type parameter it needs. Does it not end up with something like `Schema<Any>`, so `createNode` does not have any type limitations on its `fields` argument?

Comment: It doesn't, the code above has a type error. As said in the topic, interface generics are not captured by functions params within one interface, which make sense otherwise any functions of one interface could alter its generic type

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can get this to work with multiple calls. The solution that woks best would be to create a class that takes the schema definitions as an argument and check the whole object as a whole:

```
interface Node<T extends string = string> {
    name: T;
}


type Scalars = 'Int' | 'Boolean' | 'String'

type AllTypes<T extends Record<keyof T, any>> = keyof T | Scalars
type Values<T> = T[keyof T]

type SchemNodes<T extends Record<keyof T, Record<string, AllTypes<T>>>> =
    { [P in Extract<keyof T, string>]: Node<P> }

class Schema<T extends Record<keyof T, Record<string, AllTypes<T>>>> {
    constructor(types: T) { }
    getNodes(): SchemNodes<T> {
        return null!;
    }
    renderTypes(types: Array<Values<SchemNodes<T>>>) { }
}

const s = new Schema({
    "User": { posts: "Post" },
    "Blog": { users: "User" },
    // "Comment": {},
    "Post": { title: "String", comments: 'Comment' }
})

const { Blog, Post, User } = s.getNodes();
```

[Play](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgHIHsAmEA8AVZCAD0hEwGdlywpQBzZAXipvoD5kBvAWAChkByEHAC2EAFzI8Abj4BfPot5gAngAcUAZQRwANnCiVmAcgCS4Y8gA+yYwCF06XRDghLN45tYg6xpao1kAEFdXTx1CHJ8QhIIMkoAJQgEdChMHABrCBV0GCkAGmRXFTYOZiycvIIbbT0Dcj4AlAA1PQBXSPwyqQBtCtypAF1-CORtAAsIEQxsKIJiUgpkJJS0zOyBvEKV1PTqWh9CkLCIudLSpj5BLmQegAVkUGQAURIoRDB1yoKWA7o2QaSGa4O4cBS8PgIfTkSgTKZwaILOJLHZrfpVbbJXY4fb0I6hcIaM7nLhXQQpED7NoIMCpAAUTXIkjwAEobuDrnQIGBgeQ6SzJHDplhOngODx+NdBFBuW0oCAhG1QgBCWSSgQc6XI6CEyIM06SIJQd4qHCtXQdKJC3ldUpszjIcHgyHoSlgKhMIQQADuYwQkxEcDpEuuACIAKrkaChyQOtToahM5Chu4JsChx35MkCUN2XToOgxm5tKOGSQR0sZuRZ9XIAD0deTAGF0CIxOAi5xq9nk6nqJ3kGBgGBnOWvH9Q4UUm24mAk8YWzOLI75CylBTqDc8wXCn2wIVI9BHZ7yAA6Lk8kV8lnSIA)

Comment: Thanks for your answer Titian . While I did say "even with a slightly different API", it's mandatory that the API allows splitting node definitions across several files as there might be thousands of types/nodes defined. FYI, this is related to http://nexus.js.org, a graphql schema construction library, which currently generates ts definitions at runtime. I'm exploring ways to have the same level of type-safety through static typings

Comment: @FlavianDesverne Yeah, I get what you are saying. I might try again. Changing the type of the variable as methods are called might be possible(especially in the next version with custom assertions). The big problem is how do you know when `User` is registered that `Post` will be registered later. There is no way to do that unless you check at the end after everything is registered.

Comment: TBH, I don't think it's possible, coming to SO was my last attempt to find a TS wizard.
If no node/type is registered, `fields` should simply be of type `Scalars`. To be able to reference `Post` without error, you'd first need to create it with all its scalars field, then pass it to `render` to register it, and then reference it from another type (eg: `User`). Nexus achieves that by generating global ts definitions at runtime given the types passed to `render`. Using an interface was an attempt to remove these gen'd global ts definitions by sharing a single generic across several functions

Comment: @FlavianDesverne Would you be interested in a solution where you call `s.createNode` but that does not return the node. You must instead call something like `s.allNodes`. With `s.allNodes` not being valid until all dependencies have been satisfied ? If you want we ca chat on gitter maybe refine the solution

Comment: Pinged you on gitter, happy to chat anytime!